# Looking for Bluetooth Low Energy API for windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, bluetooth-lowenergy

I just finished developing a Bluetooth Low Energy application on two ESP32 boards in which I used the GATT protocol. Now I need to write an application for my personal computer in order to communicate with my ESP32 devices. I'm new to this and need advice on how to get started.

The computer will act as a server. I want to write an application in Java (but if this is not possible, I can also use C). The operating system on the computer is Windows 7. The question is: where can I get the API for writing a program. It does not have to be a high-level library, maybe low-level access is enough for me (with examples of use). My bluetooth adapter: Mpow BH456F (Supports bluetooth 5 and windows 7).

If there is no API directly from Windows, maybe there is a possibility in some other way to establish communication from my computer to the ESP32 boards? An android emulator?

I found several libraries (TinyB, SmartGattLib, that organize ble links. Will any of them work with my OS?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 does not have any built-in BLE support. Assuming your Bluetooth device is connected to your PC over USB, you have some options:

1. Use some alternative USB driver that can redirect all HCI packets to a user-mode application. Then run any Bluetooth host stack using this HCI interface that supports BLE of your choice.
2. Use VirtualBox to get a Linux machine where BLE is supported, and run your BLE program inside that. Attach the USB Bluetooth device to the VM instead of to Windows in the menu in VirtualBox.
3. Upgrade to Windows 10?

Comment: Thanks. Where can I get an API for working with an alternative usb driver? Can you show me an example?